# Adding an item to GridViewItem using SQLite

Tags: c#, sqlite, uwp

I've updated the code today .

It's something like adding a contact in mobile phone, I tried to add new item (from database) to gridViewItem using SQLite.

No error, but no result, I mean nothing happened at all.

Please check.

My xaml code:

```
<Page
x:Class="HNT_listView2.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:HNT_listView2"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:data="using:HNT_listView2.Models"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background= "Salmon" Margin="0,0,10,0"  >

    <GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind MyContactList}" 

              RightTapped="GridViewItem_RightTapped"
              IsRightTapEnabled="True"
       IsItemClickEnabled = "True"
        ItemClick = "GridViewItem_Click" Name = "NameOf_ItemClick" Margin="0,10,10,234" >


        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Contact">


                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Orientation="Horizontal">


                    <Image Width="100" Height="120" Source="{x:Bind Photo}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                           Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{x:Bind Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        <TextBlock FontSize="30" Text="{x:Bind Phone}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </StackPanel>

            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>

    </GridView>
    <Button x:Name="Add" Content="Add a contact" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,579,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Height="29" Width="120" Click="Add_Click"/>
    <Button x:Name="Retrieve" Content="Refesh" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,579,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Height="29" Width="120" Click="Refresh_Click"/>

    <TextBox x:Name="name_textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,411,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="0" Width="157">

    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="name_textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,427,0,0" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Add name" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>


    <TextBox x:Name="phone_textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,527,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="0" Width="157">

    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="phone_textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,485,0,0" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Add phone number" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>


    <TextBox x:Name="photo_textBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="183,473,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="0" Width="157">

    </TextBox>
    <TextBlock x:Name="photo_textBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,539,0,0" 
               TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Add photo" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>



</Grid>
```

My MainPage.xaml.cs code:

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private List<Contact> MyContactList;

    string path;
    SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection connection;


    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyContactList = ContactManager.GetContacts();

        path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
        connection = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
        var f = connection.CreateTable<Contact>();



    }

    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
 var s = connection.Insert(new HNT_listView2.Models.Contact
        {
            Name = name_textBox.Text,
            Phone = phone_textBox.Text,
            Photo = photo_textBox.Text

        });
        Debug.WriteLine("Added");
    }

    public void Refresh_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var query = connection.Table<Contact>();
        string name = "";
        string phone = "";
        string photo = "";

        foreach (var x in query)
        {
            name = name + "" + x.Name;
            phone = phone + "" + x.Phone;
            photo = photo + "" + x.Photo;
        }
        HNT_listView2.Models.ContactManager.GetContacts().Add(new Contact { Name = "" + name,Phone=""+phone, Photo=""+photo });
```

}
        }

My Contact.cs (for binding data):

```
public class Contact
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Photo { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}


public class ContactManager
{
    public static List<Contact> GetContacts()
    {
        var contact1 = new List<Contact>();
        contact1.Add(new Contact { Name = "Nguyen Van A", Phone = "0168111222", Photo = "Assets/1.jpg" });
        contact1.Add(new Contact { Name = "Tran Van B", Phone = " 0168333444", Photo = "Assets/2.jpg" });
        contact1.Add(new Contact { Name = "Le Van C", Phone = "0166555666", Photo = "Assets/3.jpg" });          
        return contact1;
    }
}
```

Please help !

Any reply will be appreciated ! Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The List class hasn't implemented [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) interface. So it will not update UI when you add new item in list.

You could use [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.100).aspx) (`ObservableCollection<Contact>`) to replace it.

```
public class ContactManager
{
    public static ObservableCollection<Contact> GetContacts()
    {
        var contact1 = new ObservableCollection<Contact>();
        contact1.Add(new Contact { Name = "Nguyen Van A", Phone = "0168111222", Photo = "Assets/1.jpg" });
        contact1.Add(new Contact { Name = "Tran Van B", Phone = " 0168333444", Photo = "Assets/2.jpg" });
        contact1.Add(new Contact { Name = "Le Van C", Phone = "0166555666", Photo = "Assets/3.jpg" });
        return contact1;
    }
}
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private ObservableCollection<Contact> MyContactList;
    private string path;
    private SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection connection;

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        MyContactList = ContactManager.GetContacts();
        path = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");
        connection = new SQLite.Net.SQLiteConnection(new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(), path);
        var f = connection.CreateTable<Contact>();
    }

    private void Add_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var s = connection.Insert(new HNT_listView2.Models.Contact
        {
            Name = name_textBox.Text,
            Phone = phone_textBox.Text,
            Photo = photo_textBox.Text
        });
        Debug.WriteLine("Added");
    }

    public void Refresh_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var query = connection.Table<Contact>();
        string name = "";
        string phone = "";
        string photo = "";

        foreach (var x in query)
        {
            name = name + "" + x.Name;
            phone = phone + "" + x.Phone;
            photo = photo + "" + x.Photo;
        }
        MyContactList.Add(new Contact { Name = "" + name, Phone = "" + phone, Photo = "" + photo });
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added some lines , you please check here: https://codepaste.net/dpz6vd
///////. New error "Cannot implicitly convert type .List to type .Observable" .
I also found this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202(v=vs.100).aspx) but not worked.

Answer (score 0):

It actually is not the INotifyPropertyChanged-interface that your list-class is missing but the [INotifyCollectionChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx)-interface (implemented by ObservableCollection as Xavier said)

Comment: I've added some lines , you please check here: https://codepaste.net/dpz6vd
///////. New error "Cannot implicitly convert type .List to type .Observable" .
I also found this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653202(v=vs.100).aspx) but not worked.

Comment: @HanNhuThien It seemed that you have not understood what I said. The ObservableCollection<T> class has implemented INotifyPropertyChanged interface, you don’t need to implement it again.
I have updated my reply. I edited the MainPage and ContactManager class code. Please refer to it for reference.

Comment: Oh thank you @XavierXie-MSFT. It works (actually I changed some lines :
 private ObservableCollection<Contact> MyContactList;

        public ObservableCollection<Contact> Convert<Contact>(IEnumerable<Contact> MyContactList)
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<Contact>(MyContactList);
        }

Comment: I can update new items without errors, but there are 2 problems: 1 . It does not update my added stuff but "Window.UI.Xaml.Control ...." or sth like that regardless of what I added . 2. When I close the app, I want to get all added infomation to be saved ///// Then what should I do ? Please help

Comment: @HanNhuThien I think you might need an entire code sample to learn how to execute CRUD operation by binding/bind in UWP. Please check this sample for details:[UWP-SQLite-Sample](https://github.com/XamlBrewer/UWP-SQLite-Sample/tree/master/XamlBrewer.Uwp.SqLiteSample)

Comment: Oh thank you. It's quite hard for me to see through it, though. Uhm, I'll try.